# Exporting values to existing Excel Macro-Enabled workbook template

Tags: excel, perl, templates

I want extract values from text file and export those values to an existing Excel Macro-Enabled workbook template. The excel file generate histogram when the values from text file are exported into it. When I run my script, it says cannot open file because the file format or file extension is not valid. I tried converting .xlsm to .xlsx and the values are exported into the exixting excel file but the histogram is gone. May I know how to resolve this? Below is the script I am using.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw(gunzip $GunzipError);

{
    my $output_fn = 'result.xlsm';
    my $input_fn = 'input.txt.gz';
    my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( $output_fn );
    my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
    my $zip = IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new( $input_fn )
      or die "gunzip failed: $GunzipError\n";
 
    my $col = 0;
    my $row = 1;
    while (!$zip->eof()) {
        my $line = $zip->getline();
        chomp($line);
        next if $line !~ /\S/;  # skip empty lines
        my $value = $line;
        $worksheet->write( $row, $col, $value );
        $row++;
    }
    $workbook->close();
}
```

Comment: *"I tried converting .xlsm to .xlsx "* : How did you convert the file?

Comment: Maybe you can generate the histogram with [Excel::Writer::XLSX::Chart](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX::Chart) ? Then you don't have to modify the existing `.xlsm` file?

Comment: I used online xlsm to xlsx converter. Lets say I already have histogram generating excel file which is the macro-enabled worksheet, why it says cannot open file because the file format or file extension is not valid? Is there any way of opening the macro worksheet using Perl script?

Comment: *"why it says cannot open file"* It might be that you have the file open in the Microsoft Excel program at the same time? Then it is not possible to open it in the Perl script at the same time

Comment: No, the file was not open. I tried with different converter and the values are exported but all the histogram and other charts were gone. I guess the values were overwritten the exixting histogram. May i know how to resolve this? Is there any way to export the values to first coulumn only since the values are in column oriented in the text file? Please do help me with this.

Comment: Can you send me an example of the `.xlsm` file? Then I can have a look at it. (You can find my email in my profile)

Comment: sure, will reach you through email.